# element not responsive using 'hide-sm' directive in Angular-material

Tags: angular-material

I have a filters section that is comprised of different . One of the container is 'Sort'. I wish to not have it to appear on a mobile viewport. I added the 'hide-sm' directive to md-input container. However, it doesn't seem to to work. Am i missing sthg here?

```
<md-input-container hide-sm>
        <label>Sort</label>
        <md-select ng-model="order">
            <md-option value= "expression"> 
                expression - asc 
            </md-option>
            <md-option value= "-expression"> 
                expression - dsc
            </md-option>
            </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
```

I have included the Angular Material script in my index file.

Answer (score 1):

try to use 'hide-xs' which hide element width < 600px

[check here differ APIs to responsively show or hide elements](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options)

```
<md-input-container hide-xs>
    <label>Sort</label>
    <md-select ng-model="order">
        <md-option value= "expression"> 
            expression - asc 
        </md-option>
        <md-option value= "-expression"> 
            expression - dsc
        </md-option>
        </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```